# Vue-slider-component does not show up in DOM after npm install

Tags: vue.js, npm, npm-install, vue-slider-component

I am using Vue-Slider-Component(V 3.0.31) in my application and it used to work perfectly fine. Later when I ran npm install for some other purpose, the slider stopped showing up in the browser and I can not even see that in DOM. Basically it is not rendering. I figured out the version of vue-slider-component got updated to 3.0.33 and then I tried to reinstall it again. 
I see something weird is happening. Few times when I try to install vue-slider-component, the default version comes up in package.json is

```
"vue-slider-component": "^3.0.31"
```

and the slider works perfectly fine. However, sometimes upon reinstalling, the default version comes up as-

```
"vue-slider-component": "^3.0.33"
```

and with this the slider component does not show up. My code to include slider is in place. I am only trying to figure out why is this happening.I am saving this dependency as a dev dependency in my package.json.

I have removed ^ (to make sure the version doesn't get updated) and when I try to manually install version 3.0.31, it still does not show up.I see the version is same in my package.json and package-lock.json.

I have even tried deleting node-modules and reinstalled but it does not seem to be working.

Can someone help me understand what is exactly happening here and why I am seeing this issue.

Comment: Might be an issue with another package breaking things for you. Try removing the `^` and any latest packages you've installed lately to figure out what's going on there.

Comment: I have removed ^ but still no luck. Apparently there is no error thrown when I compile my code or run it.

Comment: You might share a minimal repo to get some help. It's possible that a (peer-)dependency is breaking something.

Comment: Do not save it under `devDependencies` - save it under `dependencies` in your `package.json`

Comment: I tried adding in dev-dependencies, it does not work either.

Comment: I tried replacing the Vue-slider-component folder inside node_modules and it works but I am not sure if I can check in that?